# How to find the time complexity of a algorithm of a series ?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, series

How can I find the complexity of the following algorithm that produce the summation of a series .

series: 1+(1+2)+(1+2+3)+.......+(1+2+3+...+n)

algorithm:

```
 for(i=1; i<=n; i++){
       for(j=1; j<=i; j++){
           sum = sum + j;
       }
 }
```

Comment: The time complexity is O(1). You can translate the sum of sums to a single polynomial of n.

Comment: @AxelKemper that's not the case, it obviously cannot be O(1) because the number of iterations is not constant.

Comment: The complexity equals the number of terms, itself a triangular number. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find **time complexity**, let's analyse how many times the core (inside the loops) is run.

The outside loop is run n times, so complexity is **at least** O(n).

The inside loop is run

- once when i=1
- twice when i=2
- ... n times when i=n

So the total number of times it will be run is the sum of integers between 1 and n: (n * (n+1)) / 2 = n^2 / 2 + n / 2, which is **O(n^2)**.

**Space complexity** on the other hand is simpler in this case. As memory requirements don't depend on the input length, space complexity of the algorithm above is **O(1)** (meaning the amount of memory needed is the same (basically the size of `sum`) regardless of n, and weather the result fits in `sum`).

Note that for the same task, different algorithms may have different complexities. As @AxelKemper correctly noted in his comment, you can express the solution as a single polynomial of n, so the most efficient solution would have the complexity of O(1). However, the algorithm above does not work that way and has a higher complexity.

Answer (score 0):

The sum

> 1+(1+2)+(1+2+3)+.......+(1+2+3+...+n)

is equal to

> 1/2(1+1) + 2/2(2+1) + 3/2(3+1)+.......+n/2(n+1)

This can be rewritten as

> 1/2(1+2+...+n) + 1/2(1+4+9+....+n*n)

This in turn leads to

> n/4(n+1) + 1/12(2n^3 + 3n^2 + n)

which can be simplified to

> n^3/6 + n^2/2 + n/3

Ignoring the wordlength of `n`, the complexity to evaluate this polynomial does not depend on `n`.

**Therefore, the time complexity of the problem is `O(1)`**

The time complexity of the shown algorithm is `O(n^2)` as explained in the accepted answer.

Comment: The complexity in terms of the number of digits of `n` isn't constant. It will be close to `O(d log d)`.

Comment: This is also a correct answer that highlights something very important. The complexity of an algorithm is different from the complexity of the problem, which could be defined as the complexity of the most efficient algorithm that solves the problem. The complexity of the *problem* in the question (defined this way) is indeed O(1). Thank you for the insight!

Comment: And @YvesDaoust also has a good point. When saying that time complexity is O(n^2), it's also very important what we mean by n.